# What Trouble Ticket system would you recommend?

Tags: helpdesk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good web based trouble ticket systems?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15608/what-are-some-good-web-based-trouble-ticket-systems)

Hi
I am looking for a simple trouble ticketing system for my small software development company. It should be web based, preferrably an open source for self hosting, but cheap hosted service is okay too.

The main feature should be e-mail submitting of new tickets.

Thanks for helping.

EDIT:
This is for customer support. For internal activities (projects, plans, bugs etc) we use Redmine.

Comment: see also - http://serverfault.com/search?q=ticket+system && http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ticket+system

Answer (score 2):

Is this for tech support or for some sort of Bug Tracking?

We use [SysAid](http://www.ilient.com/) which suits us very well, and is free for our purposes.

EDIT: SysAid is a web-based helpdesk application.

For your purposes, I think SysAid would be very good for you to try anyways.  And the new version comes out tomorrow I believe.

Comment: Does the customers sending requests by email require to have an previously created account?

Comment: I am not sure on that one.  I think there are provisions for that, however we use pre-created accounts.  You might just create a generic account for "guest user"

Answer (score 2):

We use [**Mantis Bug Tracker**](http://www.mantisbt.org/). It's a free online bug tracking system and it works very well for us. It emails you whenever you've got a new bug, etc. Give it a peek and see if it'll do what you need it to do (it's pretty flexible and easy to set up).

Answer (score 2):

I had good success with Best Practical's RT: http://www.bestpractical.com/rt/

Answer (score 1):

[CodeSmith Insight](http://www.codesmithinsight.com) is a help desk software with advanced application integration. It can handle your emails and user feedback, as well as your applications error and crash reports. Everything is in one place and you can reply to an error report just as easily as you can reply to an email.

Answer (score 0):

For your consideration: http://www.zendesk.com/

Answer (score 0):

<3 Tender http://www.tenderapp.com . Any emails sent to it creates an "issue" (case). Depending on which email addy is used, you can create different buckets to drop the emails into. Users do not need accounts. You can allow users to set up accounts or, alternatively, set the whole thing to "Private" and they can only see the discussions they have created. Very slick.